# SerializationException. Ошибка при десериализации BinaryFormatter. Недопустимый двоичный формат входного потока

Tags: c#, сокет, сериализация, deserialize

Пишу клиент- серверное приложение аля google doc. Данные передаются по сокету (протокол TCP).

У клиента есть свой ричбокс, при изменении которого формируется объект (Package), который отправляется серверу для изменения буфера сервера (буфер сервера- это просто строка).

Я тестирую программу с 2ух компьютеров. На 1 запускаю приложения клиента и сервера, на другом только клиента. Одновременно ввожу текст в два ричбокса. Все нормально, пока на клиенте **КОТОРЫЙ НА КОМПЬЮТЕРЕ, ГДЕ НЕ ЗАПУЩЕН СЕРВЕР (наверно это важно)** не возникает исключение при десериализации:

> SrializationException Недопустимый двоичный формат входного потока.

Не понимаю почему его нет, а потом оно возникает?

Код получения данных клиентом от сервера:

```
private void RecieveServerPackage()
    {
        byte[] serializedPackage;
        int receivedBytes;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                serializedPackage = new byte[serverSocket.SendBufferSize];
                receivedBytes = serverSocket.Receive(serializedPackage); // Получаем от сервера сериализованный пакет

                if (receivedBytes > 0)
                {
                    ProcessData(serializedPackage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Соединение потеряно: " + ex.Message);
                if (serverSocket.Connected) serverSocket.Disconnect(false);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Код сериализации объекта:

```
public byte[] SerializePackage()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        try { bf.Serialize(ms, this); }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при сериализации BinaryFormatter : {0}", ex.ToString()); }
        byte[] serializedPackage = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return serializedPackage;
    }
```

Код десериализации объекта в конструкторе **(здесь выбрасывается исключение при попытке десериализации)**:

```
public Package(byte[] serializedPackage) // Конструктор получает сериализованный покет и десиарилизует в объект
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(serializedPackage);
        Package deserializedPackage = null;

        try { deserializedPackage = (Package)bf.Deserialize(ms); }
        catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("SOCKETLIB Ошибка при десериализации BinaryFormatter: {0}", ex.ToString()); }
        ms.Close();

        packageType = deserializedPackage.packageType;
        clientId = deserializedPackage.clientId;
        text = deserializedPackage.text;
        position = deserializedPackage.position;
        lenth = deserializedPackage.lenth;
    }
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что `BinaryFormatter` уже устарел и выпилен разработчиками из .NET? Вы в курсе, что он [является критически небезопасным](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) способом десереализации данных, при этом обеспечить безопасность при десереализации технически невозможно? Тогда почему вы его используете?

Comment: Честно говоря да, слышал. Я пишу данное приложение исключительно в учебных целях, поэтому безопасность мне не важна. К сожалению, другие способы сериализации объекта мне не знакомы,. Подскажете что-то?

Comment: `в учебных целях` - так учитесь писать не дырявое сито, а правильно. В учебных целях такое вытворять еще более недопустимо, чем в рабочих.

Comment: Что вы советуете использовать для сериализации объекта?

Comment: Берите любой JSON сериализатор и передавайте данные как UTF8 текст. Есть 2 наиболее популярных варианта: для устаревших версий .NET типа Framework 4.x есть NuGet пакет `Newtonsoft.Json`, для более новых версий .NET есть встроенный `System.Text.Json`. Информации про эти сериализаторы полинтернета.

Comment: Вас понял. Спасибо!

Comment: То, что вы отправили данные с сервера одним вызовом, ещё не означает, что на клиенте они будут вычитаны одним вызовом Receive. Нужно отправлять длину пакета, и читать в буфер данные, пока весь массив не придёт. На локальной машине работает, т.к. пересылка идёт очень быстро. По сети - вам придётся заводить промежуточный буфер. Так что или отправляйте длину, или делайте маркёр окончания передачи.